# Where can i find a documentation of all `wallet_` RPC calls?

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript, json-rpc

Looked everywhere, and all I can find are a bunch of EIPs. Is there a document/repo somewhere listing all available RPC calls that interact with the wallet (`wallet_...`)?

Specifically, I'd like to switch a user to one of the testnets when they log into my dApp. However, `wallet_addEthereumChain`, mentioned in [EIP-3085](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3085) does not work for mainnet, or any of the 4 testnets (returns `May not specify default MetaMask chain.`), and `wallet_updateEthereumChain` mentioned in [EIP-2015](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2015), returns `May not specify default MetaMask chain.` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs you're looking for can be found on the Metamask site: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#table-of-contents

The RPC call you're looking for is indeed `wallet_addEthereumChain()`, which you've tried.

The restriction you're hitting is by design: according to the docs the call won't work... *"If the chain ID corresponds to any default MetaMask chains."*

However, there's an open issue tracking the potential removal of the check: [#10597](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/10597).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.
Seems like these are MetaMask specific? Do other Web3 wallets subscribe to the same RPC calls, and have the same effects?

Comment: Hi again - yes, these are Metamask specific. I think different wallets (i.e. providers, when you've incorporated them into your code) will have their own RPC methods. The one you've used was only added by Metamask about 10 days ago. I don't know of any other provider that lets you push the user to an alternative network via an RPC method.